# RecyclerView weird children draw

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Look at Pictures to understand the problem.

I am using GridLayoutManager with VERTICAL scroll and 2  span count

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(
            getContext(),
            2,
            RecyclerView.VERTICAL,
            false);
```

Child XML file :

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/my200dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/my100dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/my10dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/my15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/my10dp">
    ....
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

View Bind :

```
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    ItemProductBinding bind = 
    ItemProductBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);


    if (this.orientation == RecyclerView.VERTICAL) {
        bind.getRoot().getLayoutParams().width = GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    } else {
        bind.getRoot().getLayoutParams().height = GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    }



    return new ProductViewHolder(bind.getRoot());
}
```

First children drawn wrong sizes:
[image: first children drawn wrong sizes]

After I scroll(new children / redraw), children drawn in good form(what i need):
[image: after I scroll(new children / redraw), children drawn in good form(what i need)]

Recyclerview XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bill_back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/my10dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_back_arrow"
        android:text="@string/add_more_products"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:drawableTint="@color/icon_tint_color"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_product_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/my15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my20dp"
        android:text="@string/number_product"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bill_back_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberProductNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25"
        android:textColor="@color/price_text_color"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/number_product_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/number_product_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_price_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/my15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my10dp"
        android:text="@string/total_price"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/numberProductNumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalPriceNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/my15dp"
        android:text="1500DA"
        android:textColor="@color/price_text_color"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/total_price_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my10dp"
        android:text="@string/sell_product_item_list"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/totalPriceNumber" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/final_bill"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/my75dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/my75dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/my15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_money"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/totalPriceNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/number_product_text"
        app:tint="@color/icon_tint_color" />

    <com.gotocodo.hanoty.customview.CustomRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/customRecyclerViewFinal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/productList" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note: I am animating the parent of recycler view from left to right(in animation) but when I logged recycler view width and height it gave me the correct values (1025 Px / 1400Px) so the problem is not RecyclerView, I think is GridLayoutManager.

Comment: Provide the Recyclerview XML File

Comment: @SayokMajumder updated the topic with an XML file and a note, Read it please.

Comment: Try making Recycler view width MAtch Constraints/0dp

Comment: @SayokMajumder I tried that dude recycler view with 100% good the problem is GridLayoutManager, I will search for an alternative library in Github.

Comment: Use the basic Recycler View Instead of the One you are using

Comment: @SayokMajumder  CustomRecyclerView is the default recycler view, constraint layout with loading and empty text and icons, and default recycler view.

Comment: @SayokMajumder I am using the same recycler view in other fragments and worked well

Comment: @SayokMajumder tnx dude I just tried what you said width 0dp and add other attrs, look to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I change CustomRecycerView XML to be like this:

```
<com.gotocodo.hanoty.customview.CustomRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/customRecyclerViewFinal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/productList"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />
```

and it is work 100%.